# Something like jQuery.extend() but standalone?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to merge two configuration objects together, something like:

```
var developmentConfig = {
  url: "localhost",
  port: 80
};

var productionConfig = {
  url: "example.com"
};

var config = isDevelopment ? developmentConfig : jQuery.extend(developmentConfig, productionConfig);
```

However, this is a Node.js app and I don't want to include jQuery and am looking for something similar but standalone. I know I could write something similar myself but I'd rather use something tested and proven (there are edge cases, complications when the config objects use richer hierarchies etc.)

**Edit**: Simple iteration is not enough because that does not handle hierarchical structures. Neither does Underscore's `extend`.

Comment: There's a website that really helps with checking jQuery's source. For `jQuery.extend`, [here you go](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.extend).

Comment: I did have a look before asking but there are external dependencies from the extend() function so there's more work to do than just to copy a few lines.

Comment: You can also check the development file: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js extend depends on isFunction, isArray, isPlainObject, isWindow, type... Yes, there are many dependencies but it's not overwhelming

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If all you need is extend, then it's pretty simple to write that in a couple of lines. If you want recursive extension, it's tricky to do that completely generically if you want have circular structures, objects with complex prototype chains, etc. If it's just some nested plain objects, then this should work:

```
function extend (target, source) {
  target = target || {};
  for (var prop in source) {
    if (typeof source[prop] === 'object') {
      target[prop] = extend(target[prop], source[prop]);
    } else {
      target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

If you're looking for a lightweight library that does this (minus the recursion, for the reasons listed above) and other similar functions not provided by javascript, look at [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) which is available via NPM for node too.

Comment: I need recursive behavior too, see the question.

Comment: this will also convert your arrays to objects.

Answer (score 5):

One more example of simple standalone function for future pilgrims across this question with protection from merge of the properties of different types:

```
function extend(obj) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function(source) {
        if (source) {
            for (var prop in source) {
                if (source[prop].constructor === Object) {
                    if (!obj[prop] || obj[prop].constructor === Object) {
                        obj[prop] = obj[prop] || {};
                        extend(obj[prop], source[prop]);
                    } else {
                        obj[prop] = source[prop];
                    }
                } else {
                    obj[prop] = source[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
extend({ name:'Maria', address:{ city:'Moscow', street:'Lenina str, 52' } }, { name:'Marianna', address:{ zip:1200003 }})
=> { name:'Marianna', address:{ city:'Moscow', street:'Lenina str, 52', zip:1200003 } }
```

Comment: first "if" in "for": source[prop] !== null && source[prop].constructor === Object

Answer (score 3):

This solution creates a **new object** and is able to handle **multiple objects**.

Furthermore, it is **recursive** and you can chose weather you **want** to **overwrite Values** and **Objects**.

```
    function extendObjects() {

        var newObject        = {};
        var overwriteValues  = false;
        var overwriteObjects = false;

        for ( var indexArgument = 0; indexArgument < arguments.length; indexArgument++ ) {

            if ( typeof arguments[indexArgument] !== 'object' ) {

                if ( arguments[indexArgument] == 'overwriteValues_True' ) {

                    overwriteValues = true;            
                } else if ( arguments[indexArgument] == 'overwriteValues_False' ) {

                    overwriteValues = false;                             
                } else if ( arguments[indexArgument] == 'overwriteObjects_True' ) {

                    overwriteObjects = true;     
                } else if ( arguments[indexArgument] == 'overwriteObjects_False' ) {

                    overwriteObjects = false; 
                }

            } else {

                extendObject( arguments[indexArgument], newObject, overwriteValues, overwriteObjects );
            }

        }

        function extendObject( object, extendedObject, overwriteValues, overwriteObjects ) {

            for ( var indexObject in object ) {

                if ( typeof object[indexObject] === 'object' ) {

                    if ( typeof extendedObject[indexObject] === "undefined" || overwriteObjects ) {
                        extendedObject[indexObject] = object[indexObject];
                    }

                    extendObject( object[indexObject], extendedObject[indexObject], overwriteValues, overwriteObjects );

                } else {

                    if ( typeof extendedObject[indexObject] === "undefined" || overwriteValues ) {
                        extendedObject[indexObject] = object[indexObject];
                    }

                }

            }     

            return extendedObject;

        }

        return newObject;
    }

    var object1           = { a : 1, b : 2, testArr : [888, { innArr : 1 }, 777 ], data : { e : 12, c : { lol : 1 }, rofl : { O : 3 } } };
    var object2           = { a : 6, b : 9, data : { a : 17, b : 18, e : 13, rofl : { O : 99, copter : { mao : 1 } } }, hexa : { tetra : 66 } };
    var object3           = { f : 13, g : 666, a : 333, data : { c : { xD : 45 } }, testArr : [888, { innArr : 3 }, 555 ]  };

    var newExtendedObject = extendObjects( 'overwriteValues_False', 'overwriteObjects_False', object1, object2, object3 );
```

**Contents of newExtendedObject:**

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"testArr":[888,{"innArr":1},777],"data":{"e":12,"c":{"lol":1,"xD":45},"rofl":{"O":3,"copter":{"mao":1}},"a":17,"b":18},"hexa":{"tetra":66},"f":13,"g":666}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o0gb2umb/