# How can I make a .extend() function for my library?

Tags: javascript, extend

I am working on a jQuery-like JavaScript library. Here is the basic code:

```
(function(){
    var package = {
        version: "0.1.0",
    },
    ZeTex = function(selector){
        // ZeTex is really a masked version of the ZeTex.fn.init object.
        return new ZeTex.fn.init(selector);
    };
    ZeTex.fn = ZeTex.prototype = {
        init: function(selector){
            if(selector){
                if(typeof slector = "object") {
                    this[0] = selector;
                } else if(typeof selector = "string") {
                    this[0] = document.querySelectorAll();
                }
                return this; 
            } else {
                return this;
            }
        }
    };
    ZeTex.fn.init.prototype = ZeTex.fn;

    ZeTex.extend = ZeTex.fn.extend = function(){
        //code
    };


    window.ZeTex = window.$ = ZeTex;
})();
```

How can I complete the `.extend()` function?

Thank you.

Comment: how about borrow that function from jQuery library ?

Comment: you may read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317003/something-like-jquery-extend-but-standalone).