# Optimize general edit function

Tags: javascript, object

I'm building a general purpose editing function. It will receive two objects as arguments. The first object will contain 3 attributes that could have been populated. This means that some fields can be undefined.

The second object will be the original one. This will be used to populate all undefined values that haven't been changed within the edited object. The original object will, always, have all properties populated. The edited one, just a few.

Function:

```
var editSword = function(edited, original) {
        var sword = {};
        sword.name          = edited.name          || original.name;
        sword.createdById   = edited.createdById   || original.createdById;
        sword.createdByName = edited.createdByName || original.createdByName;
    return sword;
}
```

Example:

```
editSword ( 
  { name: 'Rubilacxe' },
  { name: 'Excalibur', createdById: 25, createdByName:'Lorem Ipsum Dolor' }
);
```

With this function call, the returned object should be:

```
{ name: 'Rubilacxe', createdById: 25, createdByName: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor' }
```

But, how do I do to avoid checking all the fields of the sword? Let's suppose I'm changing the sword's name, but the sword has 40 attributes and each one of them will be checked against 'edited.attr'. I'm thinking in something like bracket notation, but I'm pretty new to JS and I can't figure out how to do it.

In summary, I want to know how to do something simple without waste of resource and, most important, that don't need change on the code if I create another attribute for sword.

Comment: You could take a look at underscore `_.default` and see how they do it. By the way, you left out the `createdById` property name in your test data.

Comment: `for (var property in object)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `for (var property in object)` construct. Remember to check [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) though, to include only the direct properties of that object.

Example:

```js
var editSword = function(edited, original) {
    for (var property in original) {
        if (original.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            edited[property] = edited[property] || original[property];
        }
    }
    return edited;
}

var edited = editSword ( 
  { name: 'Rubilacxe' },
  { name: 'Excalibur', id: 25, other:'Lorem Ipsum Dolor' }
);

console.log(edited);
```

*Note*: to avoid changing the passed in object, you should make use of a temporary object just like you have in your question.

```
var editSword = function(edited, original) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var property in original) {
        if (original.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            temp[property] = edited[property] || original[property];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Edit: (after op's comment)

It seems you are trying to do it the other way round, overwriting original object with those of the edited one. In that case, the code you came up with in the comments would work:

```
var editSword = function(edited, original) { 
    var temp = original; //Avoiding confusion. 
    for (var property in edited) { 
        temp[property] = edited[property]; 
    } 
    return temp; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I think that I'mlooking for something like this. Your code has given me a great insight. The problem is: the original object will always have ALL the properties.

The passed in objects aren't the real objects, they both are copies. So, I'm  trying to adapt your code so I can return the original object with changes from the edited one.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza: In that case, you can directly change the argument as it is passed by reference, temp one not required.

Comment: var editSword = function(edited, original) {
    var temp = original; //Avoiding confusion.
    for (var property in edited) {
          temp[property] = edited[property];
    }
    return temp;
}


This solved my problem. I'll ask you to add it to your answer, so it can be easily find in the best answer. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @RodrigoSouza: Added to the answer. Thanks. I interpreted the question the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the most often used solution:

```
var editSword = function(edited, original) {
    var sword = {};
    for (var prop in original) {
        if (original.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            sword[prop] = edited[prop] || original[prop];
        }
    }
    return sword;
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` check is used to ignore other possible properties through the prototype chain.

This question may also be of interest to you: [Something like jQuery.extend() but standalone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317003/something-like-jquery-extend-but-standalone).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think that my comment to Abhitalks fits for you too. Maybe I haven't explained it correctly. But, now, seems like I can see the way around. I'm trying new code. :)