# jQuery deep extend, replace values only, dont want new keys to be added

Tags: javascript, jquery

for eg. I have two json object,

first :

```
{
  "surname" : "Raghuvanshi",
  "work" : {
     "title": "title1"
  },
  "name" : "Navin"
}
```

second :

```
{
  "work" : {
     "title": "title2",
     "field": "field2"
  },
  "name" : "Navin"
}
```

I want a function which will allot all second object values to first object with the keys which only exists on first object

What I want:

```
{
  "surname" : "Raghuvanshi",
  "work" : {
     "title": "title2"
  },
  "name" : "Navin"
}
```

What `jQyery.extend(true, first, second)` gives

```
{
  "surname" : "Raghuvanshi",
  "work" : {
     "title": "title2",
     "field": "field2"
  },
  "name" : "Navin"
}
```

Update : I know this cannot be done with jQuery.extend(), you can provide me a javascript recursive function instead to do this.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tired ?

Comment: i tried `jQyery.extend(true, first, second)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this :-

```js
var one = {
    name: "Navin",
    surname: "Raghuvanshi",
    work: {
        title: "title1",
    }
};
var two = {
    name: "Navin",
    work: {
        title: "title2",
        field: "field2"
    }
};

function mergeValues(primary, mergeFrom) {
    var primaryKeys = Object.keys(primary);
    primaryKeys.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (typeof mergeFrom[value] !== "undefined") {
            if (typeof mergeFrom[value] !== "object") {
                primary[value] = mergeFrom[value];
            }

            if (typeof mergeFrom[value] === "object" && typeof primary[value] === "object") {
                primary[value] = mergeValues(primary[value], mergeFrom[value])
            }
        }
    });


    return primary;
}

var mergedObject = mergeValues(one, two);

console.log(mergedObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help , can you tell me how this method is different from another answer. and which is better ?

Comment: Other answer is more concise, and has taken into account if no object is passed to the function. I'd use the other answer :) I quickly wrote the above so it's not the most verbose.

Comment: I modified another answer to my needs, question is closed now

Answer (score 1):

I found an `extend` function [from nickf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12317051/3150441).

```
function extend (target, source) {
  target = target || {};
  for (var prop in source) {
    if (typeof source[prop] === 'object') {
      target[prop] = extend(target[prop], source[prop]);
    } else {
      target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

Just change it to.

```
function extend (target, source) {
  target = target || {};
  for (var prop in target) {
    if (typeof target[prop] === 'object' && typeof source[prop] === 'object') {
      target[prop] = extend(target[prop], source[prop]);
    } else if (typeof target[prop] == typeof source[prop]) {
      target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m2wbpggu/2/

Comment: i tried link on jsfiddle, on console.log title value is title1, but it should be title2

Comment: I got the answer, there should be else part with ` else {
     if(target[prop]) {
       target[prop] = source[prop];
      }
    } ` . Okay I edited your answer with my needs, Thanks for the help